# Setting hard Val acc limits on which models to save in Keras?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning

Im currently using `save_best_only` with `ModelCheckPoint`:

```
ModelCheckpoint(create_save_path(), monitor='val_acc', verbose=2,
                            save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False,
                            mode='auto', period=1)
```

However if I load a different model or the even the same model, the model doesn't have access to the previous training val_acc and start the save_best_only process from the start.

Since I will be training different model, I would just like to hard-code a value in, so that it only saves if it exceeds this value.

Is there a way to do this with ModelCheckPoint?

https://keras.io/callbacks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you have trained a model with accuracy equals to a specific value, say: 30%. When you reload and train that model, it will save models with accuracy lower than 30% and you don't want this to happen.

I have checked the source code of keras, and found `ModelCheckpoint` has an attribute named `best`, which serves as a benchmark.

[keras - ModelCheckpoint](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L687):

```
if mode == 'min':
    self.monitor_op = np.less
    self.best = np.Inf
elif mode == 'max':
    self.monitor_op = np.greater
    self.best = -np.Inf
else:
    if 'acc' in self.monitor or self.monitor.startswith('fmeasure'):
        self.monitor_op = np.greater
        self.best = -np.Inf
    else:
        self.monitor_op = np.less
        self.best = np.Inf
```

But its initializer doesn't accept this parameter:

```
def __init__(self, filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=0,
             save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=False,
             mode='auto', period=1):
```

So you may set it manually after create a `ModelCheckpoint` object, like this:

```
mcp = ModelCheckpoint(create_save_path(), monitor='val_acc', verbose=2,
                            save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False,
                            mode='auto', period=1)
mcp.best = 0.3
```